# Can a processor gpu still be used for video transcoding if the motherboard is disabled from using processor gpu?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, gpu, transcode

I am planning to get the following motherboard and cpu.

Asrock Rack e3c224d4i-14s Intel Xeon e3-1276v3

However, after reading the spec sheet on Asrock Rack/Intel Ark, the above mentioned motherboard which uses c224 chipset has processor graphics disabled. So I am wondering, does the processor graphics disabled simply means that the video output will not be able to use the integrated gpu? Will I still be able to use the integrated gpu for video transcoding?

The machine will be running as a headless media server.

Comment: What GPU will you be using?  It's likely you can use that for transcoding instead.  I'm fairly certain you can [**not** use the integrated GPU](http://streambuilder.pro/docs/enabling-iqsv/) in this case, as most transcoding programs assume a GPU device with compute capabilities is available.

Comment: ok so i need a discrete gpu. Any recommendation?